# How to implement asynchronous middleware in Nuxt.js

Tags: session, axios, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt middleware file that fetches the session from an external api. This session is used to set things such as locale, so it's important that it is fetched before any page loads. Currently it looks like this:

**middleware/session.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function ({ store }) {
  axios.get('http://example.com/getsession')
    .then(response => {
      store.commit('setSession', response)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      store.commit('clearSession')
    })
}
```

**store/index.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  session: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  setSession (state, session) {
    state.session = session || {}
  },
  clearSession (state) {
    state.session = {}
  }
}

export const getters = {
  session (state) {
    return state.session || {}
  }
}
```

The session is fetched using Axios and stored in a Vuex store. However, since it is asynchronous, this data isn't available instantly, and plugins or other middleware that try to get the session from the store simply get an empty object (which is the default).

Examples where this breaks things:

- Another middleware used for certain routes checks if the user is logged in based on the `session.user`. The session is still empty and therefore `session.user` is `undefined` at this point.
- I'm using the vue-i18n plugin to translate pages. It gets its initial locale from the session in the store. But since this session is empty at the moment it is retrieved, i18n always uses the fallback locale.

Is there a way to await the response of the api call before proceeding? Or is there maybe a different/better way to perform this api call?

Comment: How did u solve this?

Answer (score 11):

From the Nuxt documentation: ["A middleware can be asynchronous. To do this, simply return a Promise or use the 2nd callback argument"](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware)

Therefore, something like this should work, since axios returns a promise:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function ({ store }) {
  return axios.get('http://example.com/getsession')
    .then(response => {
      store.commit('setSession', response)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      store.commit('clearSession')
    })
}
```

Comment: But is it possible to return a promise from a store in the middleware? Because here, you call directly in the middleware.

Comment: @Fasco yes. Supposing that you have an action `getSession` in your Vuex store, you can return in your middleware function the value returned by the store `dispatch` method, because that's also a Promise. E.g. `return store.dispatch('getSession')`

Comment: the provided link is unrelative. use this: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware#router-middleware

Answer (score 0):

I might be late here, but for future readers, you could actually simply just make the middleware function as an asynchronous function as such:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default async function ({ store }) {
  await axios.get('http://example.com/getsession')
    .then(response => {
      store.commit('setSession', response)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      store.commit('clearSession')
    })
}
```